# Multithreading with method containing 2 parameters to return dictionary

Tags: c#, multithreading, return-type

I wrote a method that goes through a list of files and extracts values from each file and stores them into a dictionary and returns the dictionary. This method goes through a large amount of files and I receive a ContextSwitchDeadLock error because of it. I have looked into this error and I am needing to use a thread to fix this error. I am brand new to threads and would like some help with threading.

I create a new thread and use delegate to pass through the parameters dictionary and fileNames into the method getValuesNew(). I am wondering how can I return the dictionary. I have attached the method that I would like to call as well as the code in the main program that creates the new thread. Any suggestions to better my code will be greatly appreciated!

```
            //dictionary and fileNames are manipulated a bit before use in thread
            Dictionary<string, List<double>> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<double>>();
            List<string> fileNames = new List<string>();

            ...

            Thread thread = new Thread(delegate()
            {
                 getValuesNEW(dictionary, fileNames);
            });

            thread.Start();


   //This is the method that I am calling
   public Dictionary<string, List<double>> getValuesNEW(Dictionary<string, List<double>> dictionary, List<string> fileNames)
    {
        foreach (string name in fileNames)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(name);
            var collectValues = false;
            string ertNumber = null;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element))
                {
                    if (reader.Name == "ChannelID" && reader.HasAttributes)
                    {
                        if (dictionary.ContainsKey(sep(reader.GetAttribute("EndPointChannelID"))))
                        {
                            //collectValues = sep(reader.GetAttribute("EndPointChannelID")) == ertNumber;
                            collectValues = true;
                            ertNumber = sep(reader.GetAttribute("EndPointChannelID"));
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            collectValues = false;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (collectValues && reader.Name == "Reading" && reader.HasAttributes)
                    {
                        dictionary[ertNumber].Add(Convert.ToDouble(reader.GetAttribute("Value")));
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        return dictionary;
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear why on Earth you start a new thread just to parse a file. Do you need to parallelize this? And no, you don't return the dictionary from the thread anyhow, because you pass in a *reference* to the dictionary. You should first solve the reason for a `ContextSwitchDeadLock` before blindly redesigning your program.

Answer (score 1):

Others have explained why the current approach isn't getting you anywhere. If you're using .NET 4 you can use the `ConcurrentDictionary` and `Parallel.ForEach`

```
private List<double> GetValuesFromFile(string fileName)
{
      //TBD
}

private void RetrieveAllFileValues()
{
     IEnumerable<string> files = ...;
     ConcurrentDictionary<int, List<double>> dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, List<double>>();
     Parallel.ForEach(files, file =>
           {
               var values = GetValuesFromFile(file);
               dict.Add(file, values);
           });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to return the dictionary: the main thread already has a reference to it and it'll see the changes that your thread does. All the main thread has to do is wait until the delegate thread is done (for example using `thread.Wait()`).

However, doing things this way, you get no benefit from multithreading because nothing is done in parallel. What you can do is have multiple threads, and multiple dictionaries (one per thread). When everyone's done, the main thread can put all those dictionaries together.

The reason you don't want multiple threads accessing the same dictionary is that the Dictionary class is not thread-safe: its behavior is undefined if more than one thread use it at the same time. However you could use a `ConcurrentDictionary`, this one is thread-safe. What this means is that every time you read or write to the `ConcurrentDictionary`, it uses a lock to make sure to wait until no one else is using the dictionary at the same time.

Which of the two techniques is faster depends on how often your threads would be accessing the shared dictionary: if they access it rarely then a `ConcurrentDictionary` will work well. If they access it very often then it might be preferable to use multiple dictionaries and merge in the end. In your case since there is file I/O involved, I suspect that the `ConcurrentDictionary` approach will work best.

So, in short, change getValuesNEW to this:

```
//This is the method that I am calling
public void getValuesNEW(ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<double>> dictionary, List<string> fileNames)
 {
     foreach (string name in fileNames)
     {
         // (code in there is unchanged)
     }
     // no need to return the dictionary
     //return dictionary;
 }
```

Comment: That makes sense. I will have to adopt the ConcurrentDictionary into my code. So I am still trying to figure out if a thread is the best way to go then. My program is a ArcMap add-in and the reasoning for the threading is to stop the ContextSwitchDeadLock error which occurs because of the getValuesNew method locking up the UI. I dont care what happens in the UI as the getValuesNew method is running but it appears to freeze the program. As you were saying, there would be no benefit because nothing is done in parallel. Would a backgroundworker be a better approach for this? Remember 2 parameters

Comment: If you're only using multithreading to get away from the GUI thread then yes, you can also use a BackgroundWorker. You can also use a thread like here, except that you don't want to use `wait` to wait for it to be done (because that would block the UI thread and we're back to square one). What you want to do is for getValuesNEW to call you back when it's done, and have that code update the UI to show the new stuff.

Comment: the new async stuff in C# 4 may also be a way to do this.

Comment: see e.g. http://ezcodesample.com/workerGUI/workerGUI_article.html for an example of how to deal with the GUI thread limitations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait for your thread to finish, then you can use `Thread.Join` after `Thread.Start`, to get the result of your thread create a class variable or something that both your main program and your thread can use, however, i don't see the point of a thread here, unless you want to process all the files in parallel.

Comment: I was thinking about using a thread to solve the ContextSwitchDeadLock error which is freezing my UI but I think I just got side tracked from using a backgroundworker to a thread.